# how to increase the size of subview of mainview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a editor where over `UIView` I put a label and there is labeltext over the label . Now user can create as many `UIView` by writing text on `UITextView` and click on button . Now If I need to edit text , on Tapgesture I get the text and show it on the `UITextView` and user could edit that text .

Now if a user add more text then I need to increase the width of the subview over which the text will fall after clicking on the submit button . So my question is that is it possible to increase a subview width within a mainview . Here is the code through which I get all the subview from the main view

```
for (UIView *subview in mainview.subviews)
        {
            if(subview.tag==sender.tag)
            {

                for(UIView *getsusublabel in subview.subviews)
                {

                    if([getsusublabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                    {
                        UILabel *subsublabel = (UILabel *)getsusublabel;
                        subsublabel.text=imagelabeltext.text;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

here `subsublabel` is the label on subview .

Comment: You mean you want a scroll view? Don't use a label, use a text view and change the border style and edit-ability...

Comment: Yea I want to change the border style of subviews when my text increases .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase label width according to the text, try this code snippet:

```
//use this for custom font
CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChaparralPro-Bold" size:40 ]].width;

//use this for system font 
CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40 ]].width;

label.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, width,height);

//point.x, point.y -> origin for label;
//height -> your label height;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the size of the subview with the text, then you can try the folowing supposing that your subView is a label:

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                    lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

And you can try it on other subViews accordingly.

Comment: how do I get maximumLabelSize

Comment: You have to set maximumLabelSize as per your requirement by using CGSize e.g : CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300, 1000);

Comment: Ok I got the expectedLabelSize now how to put it over the subview.I have made subview autoresizeable by subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;. How do I put expectedLabelSize over the subview .

Comment: If you want to adjust the size of the label as per your text, you can put expectedLabelSize at the place where you want to make the changes in the text i.e, where you are entering or changing the text. Or else you can use a delegate for the call back as soon as the text is changed.